# Bind Controller Context with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject-2

I have a service class that is required to create a pdf, which needs the ControllerContext injected, in order to render a the `html => pdf`.
This service is called through a middle tier, that has no reference to the web/mvc project. which is fine, since ninject does all the required injection of services etc.
This is what the Service looks like (simplified for these purposes)

```
public class PdfCreatorService : AbstractUrlBasedPdfCreatorService
{
    [Inject]
    public ControllerContext ControllerContext { get; set; }

    public override byte[] CreateReport(int reportId)
    {
        var result = new PdfController().CreateReport(reportId);
        using (var it = new ResponseCapture(ControllerContext.RequestContext))
        {
            result.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
            return it.ReadAllContents();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the simplified call stack:

> Web.HomeController.SendEmailWithPdf(int id) calls:
>   MiddleTier.BusinessLogic.SendEmailWithPdf(int id) calls:
>   Web.Services.PdfCreatorService.CreateReport(int id)

Ninject is reaching PdfCreatorService, no problem, but: I need to somehow **forward the ControllerContext from the HomeController (through the middle tier) to the PdfCreatorService**.
Whilst the middle tier cannot have any reference to the ControllerContext.

I've looked at Providers, Factories, Resolver, etc.
But couldn't find the right solution.

Any help is appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: Are you calling the PdfCreatorService from your controller? If so, why don't you just pass the controllercontext as a parameter. Or even better from a design point of view, extract the information you need and pass it as simple parameters to your PdfCreatorService.

Comment: @Kenneth no, as shown in the stack, I'm not calling the PdfCreatorService directly from the controller.
Can you explain, how I'd use a simple parameter to pass the ControllerContext ?

Comment: So you are accesing this from a web service? If so, since you're not calling a controller there won't be a controllercontext available either.

Comment: I'm calling controller -> middle tier -> pdfService
The middle tier cannot have a reference to the ControllerContext though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I've come up with a solution that I'm happy with.
Here is how I'm retrieving the ControllerContext:

```
public class PdfCreatorService 
{
    [Inject]
    public ControllerContextProvider contextProvider { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public PdfController pdfController { get; set; }

    public override byte[] CreateReport(int reportId)
    {
        var context = contextProvider.GetControllerContext();
        using (var stream = new ResponseCapture(context.RequestContext))
        {
            // Setup Controller
            var routeData = new RouteData(context.RouteData.Route, context.RouteData.RouteHandler);
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "CreateReport");
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Pdf");
            routeData.Values.Add("id", reportId);
            var pdfContext = new ControllerContext(context.HttpContext, routeData, pdfController);

            // Execute Controller
            var result = pdfController.CreateReport(reportId);
            result.ExecuteResult(pdfContext);

            return stream.ReadAllContents();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how to set the context in the original controller:

```
public abstract class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Inject]
    public ControllerContextProvider ControllerContextProvider { get; set; }

    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        ControllerContextProvider.GetControllerContext = () => ControllerContext;
        return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
    }
}
```

This is what the provider class looks like:

```
public class ControllerContextProvider
{
    public Func<ControllerContext> GetControllerContext { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I'm binding it:

```
public class PortalNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ControllerContextProvider>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

Still interested to see whether anyone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Custom Controller factory.

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        HttpContext.Current.Request["controllerInstance"] = controller;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

You need to register this controller in your global.asax:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(MyControllerFactory));
```

After that you can configure Ninject to resolve the ControllerContext from the request:

```
kernel.Bind<ControllerContext>().ToMethod(ctx => ((Controller)HttpContext.Current.Request["controllerInstance"]).ControllerContext);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This feels a bit like a cheat though. Since you're just saving it into HttpContext.Current.Request. Therefor kinda bypassing ninject. Ninject is almost redundant, since the PdfService could just load it from the HttpContext.Current.Request without ninject...